# Why am I getting Object user has no method '_create' ember?

Tags: ember.js

I am getting the following error when trying to create a user using fixtureadapter:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object user has no method '_create' ember-data.js?body=1:1580
DS.Store.Ember.Object.extend.createRecord ember-data.js?body=1:1580
EmberGym.UsersCreateController.Ember.ObjectController.extend.actions.save users_create_controller.js?body=1:7
Ember.ActionHandler.Ember.Mixin.create.send ember.js?body=1:14740
(anonymous function) ember.js?body=1:33233
Backburner.run ember.js?body=1:5609
Ember.run ember.js?body=1:5974
ActionHelper.registeredActions.(anonymous function).handler ember.js?body=1:33231
(anonymous function) ember.js?body=1:19340
Ember.handleErrors ember.js?body=1:578
(anonymous function) ember.js?body=1:19332
jQuery.event.dispatch jquery.js?body=1:5096
elemData.handle jquery.js?body=1:4767
```

https://github.com/ecl1pse/ember-gym

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

Was an old version of ember-data unfortunately..

Comment: Note that if you are using ember-rails, it ships with an older version of ember-data (0.14).  The basic TodoMVC tutorial does not work with this version.  You will need to specify a new version in your `Gemfile` like `gem 'ember-data-source', '1.0.0.beta.6'`